# Add search functionality in admin for select

Tags: magento2, custom, search, adminform, select

Hi I want to add search functionality in select box in admin form.
screenshot: https://nimb.ws/Rj5osS , anyone had any idea?

I have this code which creates the field:

```
$baseFieldset->addField(
            'magento_id',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Magento Attribute'),
                'title' => __('Magento Attribute'),
                'name' => 'magento_id',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => $Mage_Attribute
            ]
        );
```